# create model on laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

I'm using lumen from laravel 5.2 and edit app_key and database info in .env file also uncomment $app->withFacades(); in bootstrap/app.php so now i can connect to my database.
the problem is i want to use model in my project but always failed.
my model store in app/Models/User.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {
  protected $table = 'user';
  protected $fillable = ['userid','name','timestamp'];
}
```

my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use DB;

use App\Models\User;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function tes(Request $request){
        $user = User::where('id','=',1)->first();

        return 'name: '.$user->name;
    }
}
```

i also tried change

```
use App\Models\User;
```

with

```
use App\User;
```

but still not working.

here my error message

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 3280:
Call to a member function connection() on null
```

in my xampp server there is also this message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in D:\Workspace\website\api\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 3280
```

what i have tried

- edit database.php in lumen-framework/config/
- copy and put database.php in app/Config/

and still not working. is there something i miss?

Comment: Did you uncomment `$app->withEloquent();` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file, too?

Comment: i didn't notice that.. its working now..

Comment: Easy to miss, done it before too. I added as answer for future readers.

Comment: yup, its my first time using laravel didn't notice that function is for this. your answer accepted. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, just need to uncomment `$app->withEloquent();` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file as well! This will allow you to use Eloquent within Lumen. From the [docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/database):

> If you would like to use the Eloquent ORM, you should uncomment the
>   `$app->withEloquent()` call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.